# ArrayList won't return modified after running through a method

Tags: java, arraylist, set, return, duplicates

I can't get this method to modify an ArrayList then return the modified ArrayList.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> sortAndRemoveDuplicates(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>(new HashSet<Integer>(list));
        Collections.sort(list);
        //System.out.println(list);
        return list;
}
```

When I uncomment the System call I can see that the ArrayList is being modified and I know that my method works but when I run the method through main the ArrayList remains unaffected. Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

Why isn't this modified version working?

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> sortAndRemoveDuplicates(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>(new HashSet<Integer>(list));
    Collections.sort(newList);
    System.out.println(newList);
    return newList;
}
```

Comment: **How** are you calling it? Are you grabbing the List that is returned?

Comment: I think your expectations are not met because everything in Java is pass by value.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating new `ArrayList` from passed list so You need to catch result back

```
List<Integer> result = sortAndRemoveDuplicates(inputList)
```

Comment: So do I run my method within my method?

Comment: you need to reassign result back just that

Answer (score 1):

Java [passes references *by value*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value). You are re-assigning the input reference that points to the initial list to another object. The original list will remain pointing to the original `ArrayList` object.

You need to assign this newly created list back to the original reference:

```
originalList = sortAndRemoveDuplicates(originalList);
```

**EDIT**: Alternatively, since you are not returning the value to the caller method (`main`), you can make your method's return type `void` and modify your input list as follows:

```
public static void sortAndRemoveDuplicates(List<Integer> list) {
    List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>(new HashSet<Integer>(list));
    Collections.sort(newList);
    System.out.println(newList);
    list.clear();
    for(Integer integer : newList) {
        list.add(integer);
    }
}
```

**Note**: It is best practice to [program to *interfaces*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) instead of concrete implementations, i.e. let your `newList` be declared of type `List` instead of `ArrayList`.

Comment: Is this within my method?

Comment: No, in `main` where you call your method.

Comment: Updated. Your edited method still won't work if you're not assigning the return value to `main`.

Comment: How would I assign the return value to main?

Answer (score 0):

I think your expectations are not met because everything in Java is pass by value so the modifications to the list are made to a copy, not your original list. Unless you return and capture the modified copy, you will not see the changes in the calling code on return from the method.